# How to do logical operations between two matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices. One is `PR1` an identity matrix and another inverse  identity matrix `PR2`. Reference Matrix A is mentioned that can be 5x5 10x10 etc. According to that I1,I2 is created.Here it is mentioned 5x5 matrix.
The logical operations start with And= PR1 AND PR2 followed by Xor= PR1 XOR PR2.

`A` matrix:

A =

```
 0     1     1     1     0     
 1     0     1     1     0     
 1     1     0     1     1     
 1     1     1     0     1    
 0     0     1     1     0
```

`I` is identity matrix

PR1 =

```
 1     0     0     0     0     
 0     1     0     0     0     
 0     0     1     0     0     
 0     0     0     1     0     
 0     0     0     0     1
```

PR2 =

```
 0     0     0     0     1     
 0     0     0     1     0     
 0     0     1     0     0     
 0     1     0     0     0     
 1     0     0     0     0
```

And =

```
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

Xor =

```
 1     0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     0
 1     0     0     0     1
```

Now scan left to right of each row in And and Xor matrices. Place the first 1 as it is in the new row that is in R1 matrix. Trace for second one and do NOR operation between first one 1 row and second 1 row in A matrix in above matrix (1,5) is second 1  place so do NOR operation between 1st and 5th row  place the answer in R1matrix. Similarly it has R1.

R1 =

```
 1     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     1
```

Now replace R1 to PR2
new
PR2 =

```
 1     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     1
```

Again repated same process PR1 AND PR2 followed by PR1 XOR PR2

And =

```
 1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1
```

Xor =

```
 0     0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     0
 1     0     0     0     0
```

Now scan left to right of each row in And and Xor matrices. Place the first 1 as it is in the new row that is in R1 matrix. Trace for second one and do NOR operation between first one 1 row and second 1 row in A matrix in above matrix (1,5) is second 1  place so do NOR operation between 1st and 5th row  place the answer in R2matrix.

R2=

```
 1     0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0
 1     0     0     0     1
```

check all column has minimum one 1 and stop

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: I need this in mat lab code

Comment: Have you searched for it? [(`Logical Operations`)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)

Comment: Logical operation I get it but R1 , R2 is problem for me

Comment: PR1 = eye(size(A,1)); I want to know how to bring PR2

Comment: you get PR2 with `fliplr(eye(size(A,1)))`. Is that all?

Comment: yes I got it. How to achieve R1. Here for eg I took 2nd row for R1 operation. Tracing left to right in And & Xor matrix placing first 1 in the place of R1 and now tracing for 2nd 1 it is found in place of (2,4). Then do NOR operation between 2nd row and 4th row put the result in R1.

Comment: A (2,:) = 1 0 1 1 0  NOR  A(4,:) =1 1  1  0 1    ; R1 (2,:) =0 0 0 0 0

Comment: In each iteration PR2 replaced by R1,R2 etc. Until reaching the solution

Answer (score 2):

PR1 AND PR2 is the same as: PR1 * PR2

C = xor(A,B)

([*source*](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xor.html)).

Finding the identity matrix there is a build in function. [Identity](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) matrix (I believe that is it, I don't know why it is called "eye")

You should really google stuff, like: "xor matlab matrix". There really isn't much thinking involved with getting these. You probably put more effort into writing your question.

Answer (score 1):

That is quite straight forward

```
PR1 = eye(size(A,1));
PR2 = flip(PR1);
AND = and(PR1,PR2);
XOR = xor(PR1,PR2);

k = find(And~=0,1,'first');
R1 = zeros(size(A,1));
R1(k) = And(k);
idx = find(Xor~=0, 1, 'first');
R1(idx) = Xor(idx);
```

and if you want to do the NOR operations for row 1 and row 5 then you do

```
R1(1,:) = !(or(A(1,:),A(5,:)))
R1(2,:) = !(or(A(2,:),A(4,:)))
R1(4,:) = !(or(A(2,:),A(4,:))) 
R1(5,:) = !(or(A(1,:),A(5,:)))

PR2 = R1
```

from here repeat your process as you need.

Comment: How to achieve R1. Here for eg I took 2nd row for R1 operation. Tracing left to right in And & Xor matrix placing first 1 in the place of R1 and now tracing for 2nd 1 it is found in place of (2,4). Then do NOR operation between 2nd row and 4th row put the result in R1.

Comment: Above has to be modified little .The tracing is done parallelly in both matrices. Means take 1st row in And & Xor matrix parallel and check for 1st 1 and follow as before

Comment: ya but And has just one 1 so what is the point of rechecking that everytime for a second 1, when we know the matrix has a single 1?

Comment: But it won't works well for 2nd And condition. So in generic it has to scan and place the first 1 in the place of where it is.